# $DISPLAY variable and its implications

Tags: xorg

I think I'm misunderstanding this variable.

1. Does each x-session have it's own display variable?
2. What does the number before the dot vs. after the dot mean, for example DISPLAY=0.0
3. Which number (before/after) represents an x-session?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each X session has its own display number. This is the number before the dot. The number after the dot is the screen within the X session.

Comment: What is meant by screen? Does this mean physical screen like running two monitors or something else?

Comment: That part is implementation-defined. On Xorg it means physical screens.